# Are all web pages HTML?

Tags: html

I see all these tools for web page creation. (Java, PHP , ASP.NET , CSS, WordPress...) When I save a web page, it's always HTML. Does that mean that all these tools are platforms for creating HTML web pages? Or are they alternatives to HTML altogether?

Also, if they *are* all HTML, why do web hosts advertise they have Linux / Windows? What does it matter?

Comment: All webpages are in the end result being tranlated to somekind of HTML as that is what browsers read. But one could output that HTML in different ways dynamically (to add content based on user/region etc.) and that requires a programming language such as PHP or Java. Some programming languages and their underlying platform run on different operating systems such as C# (runs on ASP.Net) is optimally used with Windows.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

Comment: HTML and CSS are markup languages for formatting documents; PHP, ASP.NET and Java are programming languages; and Wordpress is a web application written in PHP.

Comment: @halfer Thank you. And for the vote on my behalf. :)

Comment: Note to delete-voters. There are some _very_ helpful answers here for anyone who wants to _start_ web-programming.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of false assumption in the answers and comments. HTML isn't the only supported format for browser. XML/XSLT is a good example of a widely supported alternative. Also depending of your definition of a web page, a Flash application can also be loaded as a web page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

HTML is a markup language which your browser (Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc.) can read to render what people usually call a webpage. However, your browser can also render image files (try opening a photo with it), XML files and many other file formats.

When you try to access a URL (let's say http://www.stackoverflow.com), your computer sends a request to the server which hosts the site. Any technology can be running on the server (Java, PHP, etc.) to process your request. The server is a physical machine which can be running any OS (Windows, Linux, etc.) and software. Eventually, the server returns a response to your browser (oftentimes the response will contain an HTML page for the browser to display).

Wordpress which you mentioned is a content management system which helps people making PHP websites.

CSS is a markup language which is used to decorate HTML pages. Most HTML pages refer to a CSS stylesheet which your browser retrieves and then interprets.

Answer (score 9):

For a web page, HTML is always the "end product" sent to the browser (in addition to any images, stylesheets, script files, etc which the HTML links to).

- Java, PHP, ASP.Net are server-side languages you can use to generate HTML dynamically on the server (in comparison to just serving static HTML files)
- CSS is styling for your HTML. You either write it in the HTML page itself, or in a separate CSS file which you then link to from the HTML.
- WordPress is a complete CMS (Content Management System) built on PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

They use HTML just for the basic layout. You can do Websites which don't use any HTML. The OS of the server is just a usage/performance question for the hoster. Also I think there proprietary Windows-standards that Linux servers can't handle, but I'm not sure on that one.

Comment: "You can do Websites which don't use any HTML" - technically true I suppose. You can render text-only documents via the web, you could make a website out of just images, or only using Flash animations - but it wouldn't be a good idea! If you want a website that is well-formatted and accessible, you have to use some variant of HTML.

Comment: Jep, I was just pointing out that it is technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the client-side output is HTML in the most cases although it cannot be only that, but that is the standard. The PHP, ASP, etc. are running server-side and you cannot see them. Only exception is JavaScript, which runs clientside so you can see it if you're viewing the source, but finally, the page output will be HTML.

Note: CSS is a formatting system. WordPress is a blogsystem (or now a CMS) written in PHP. So you're mixing some basic points.

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned two different thing:
First HTML:
this is basic language for showing data on web. All pages are sent as HTML page and your browser renders HTML and shows you images and links and ...
The other thing is web programing languages like php,asp,java... . they are languages that process data like verifying user name and password and send its result as HTML to user.

---

the other thing you've mentioned about hosting:
every programing languagehas its own requirements for example if you want to write a program in ASP.NET, so you have to use windows server.
so it depents on your need to choose one.